# How to not drag an Image out of the frame?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7

I cannot find the property or the object that I need..

I have implemented a draggable and zoomable image but I can drag it out of the screen, so I lose my Image out of the view.

Where should I put my image to keep it inside a box (and, possibly with the nice bouncing effect)?

**EDIT:**

Pratically my image has to remain in the stackpanel, with only the possibility of zoom-in.
(max zoom-out as the first rendering).

A bit of code:

```
    private void OnPinchStarted(object sender, PinchStartedGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        initialAngle = compositeTransform.Rotation;
        initialScale = compositeTransform.ScaleX;
    }

    private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        compositeTransform.ScaleX = initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;
        compositeTransform.ScaleY = initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;
    }

    private void OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        compositeTransform.TranslateX += e.HorizontalChange;
        compositeTransform.TranslateY += e.VerticalChange;
    }

    <StackPanel x:Name="container">
        <Image x:Name="image_chart">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale" />
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="transform" />
                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="compositeTransform"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
            <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted" PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta"
                                         DragDelta="OnDragDelta"/>
            </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>
```

**EDIT 2 - Half Answer**

I've finally find out how to stop the zoom-out at the original size!

```
private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (1.0 <= (initialScale * e.DistanceRatio))
        {
            compositeTransform.ScaleX = initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;
            compositeTransform.ScaleY = initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;
        }
    }
```

The If condition means: if I'm zooming in -> no problem because the e.DistanceRatio is >1. If I'm zooming out I will stop until the initialScale will be the same!

Now I still need help on how avoid the Drag outside.

Comment: How you currently implemented it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I find out the solution, but I need some improvement.
The scaling work but when the image is on the right it goes all on the left (because it's scaling starting from the top_left corner..

Here's the code for the "blocking drag":

```
private void OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
    {

        double realWidth = image_chart.ActualWidth*compositeTransform.ScaleX;
        double realHeight = image_chart.ActualHeight * compositeTransform.ScaleY;

        if(compositeTransform.TranslateX>=0)
           compositeTransform.TranslateX = Math.Max(container.ActualWidth - realWidth,
                                                 Math.Min(0, compositeTransform.TranslateX + e.HorizontalChange));
        else
            compositeTransform.TranslateX = Math.Max(container.ActualWidth - realWidth,
                                                     Math.Min(0, compositeTransform.TranslateX + e.HorizontalChange));
        if(compositeTransform.TranslateY>=0)
           compositeTransform.TranslateY = Math.Max(container.ActualHeight - realHeight,
                                                 Math.Min(0, compositeTransform.TranslateY + e.VerticalChange));
        else
            compositeTransform.TranslateY = Math.Max(container.ActualHeight - realHeight,
                                                     Math.Min(0, compositeTransform.TranslateY + e.VerticalChange));
```

**EDIT:**

In the end I've decide to use the WebBrowser.. much more "smoother" and enjoyable!

Comment: Thanks @Enrichman i have tried your solution and worked for me :) but it is not smooth as equal as webBrowser can we achive this with our programming ?

Comment: Happy that this helped you! Hm, I'm not sure.. as I said in the end I gave up! Too many problems for a such simple stuff! : )

Comment: yeah... am also thinking to use webBrowser to dispaly image in my app

Comment: Yep, go for it! Much better! :]

Comment: we cant load the local images using `NavigateToString`? is there any way to do this with `NavigateToString` suggest me :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not an expert at WP7 or C#, and I don't really know! :p

Comment: @EnricoCandino FYI, Please check this: http://www.frenk.com/2011/03/windows-phone-7-correct-pinch-zoom-in-silverlight/ The example contains a complete solution which I believed to solve the "move out of edge" issue.

Answer (score 1):

my solution:

XAML code

```
<StackPanel  x:Name="Scroll" Margin="0">
                    <Image  CacheMode="BitmapCache" Name="FrontCover"   Source="{Binding FullCover}"  >
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"  />
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener   PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta" PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted" DragDelta="OnDragDelta"  />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Image>
            </StackPanel>
```

```
 double initialScale;

    private void OnPinchStarted(object sender, PinchStartedGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        initialScale = transform.ScaleX;
    }

    private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var curZoom = initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;
        if (curZoom >= 1 && curZoom <= 3)
        {
            transform.ScaleX = curZoom;
            transform.ScaleY = curZoom;

        }
    }

    private void OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        transform.CenterX = (transform.CenterX - e.HorizontalChange);
        transform.CenterY = (transform.CenterY - e.VerticalChange);

        if (transform.CenterX < 0)
            transform.CenterX = 0;
        else if ( transform.CenterX > Scroll.ActualWidth)
            transform.CenterX = Scroll.ActualWidth;
        else if (transform.CenterX > (FrontCover.Height * transform.ScaleX))
            transform.CenterX = FrontCover.Height * transform.ScaleX;

        if (transform.CenterY < 0)
            transform.CenterY = 0;
        else if (transform.CenterY > Scroll.ActualHeight)
            transform.CenterY = Scroll.ActualHeight;
        else if (transform.CenterY > (FrontCover.Height * transform.ScaleY))
            transform.CenterY = FrontCover.Height * transform.ScaleY;

    }
```

Think it should help others

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that at beginning image is in top-left corner (and please check if this still works after scaling):

```
private void OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
{
    compositeTransform.TranslateX = Math.Min(container.ActualWidth - image_chart.ActualWidth,
        Math.Max(0,
            compositeTransform.TranslateX + e.HorizontalChange));
    compositeTransform.TranslateY = Math.Min(container.ActualHeight - image_chart.ActualHeight,
        Math.Max(0,
            compositeTransform.TranslateY + e.VerticalChange));
}
```

Comment: Hm.. no, sorry, it doesn't work but you gave me a nice hint.
Check my answer!