# How to limiting the image zooming, dragging with the screen?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have made an application which displays Images and i have implemented pinch zooing, translating using `Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit, GestureService` it works perfect. but when am zooming the image or dragging the image it is not the image border/ boundaries. :(

how can i limit the image with in the screen. i want same look and feel like native windows phone photo viewer or web browser ( we can drag contetnt with in the limites only in web browser)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have posted the code on my blog.. have a look here 
http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/photoviewer-with-pinch-zoom-pan-and-flick-support/

I use the same for my app's photo viewer

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have fallowed [Enrichman answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616816/how-to-not-drag-an-image-out-of-the-frame/10635194#comment19996999_10635194). it works, but it gives bad user experience. can you plesae give me detailed explanation